# Refering to another field in a form and return entries based on the filed

Tags: ms-access, sql

Structure of DB is:

Org_Year(Table)

- ID
- Org_Name_ID
- Org_Year

Ft(Table)

- ID
- Org_Year_ID
- Count

Org_Name(Table)

- ID
- Org_Name

I've created a form to input data into Ft.
Form has reference to Org_name. I should be able to choose between different org first. Afterwards i want to choose which year to enter data into Ft for. I only want to be presented with a list of Years according to the entries in the Org_Year table, where org matches my selection in the dropdown above.

The query to populate the select box (Org_year_Box) is:

```
SELECT Org_Year
FROM Org_Year
WHERE Org_Name_ID=Organisation_Name_ID.value;
```

I't doesn't return the Years for the given Org_id when using the above query. But if i replace "Organisation_Name_ID.value" with the actual value ie. "2" it returns the correct years.

How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this..  You are missing a Group By..

```
SELECT Org_Year
FROM Org_Year
WHERE Org_Name_ID=Organisation_Name_ID.value;
Group By Org_Year.Org_Year
```